# Is Final Destination 5 the last final destination movie?

Tags: movie-franchise, final-destination, final-destination-5

In [Final Destination 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination_5), the last 2 survivors happens to be on the plane that crashed in the [first movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination). It also shows all the killing scenes from previous movies after the movie.

Does it mean that this one is the last movie in the series?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no real way to answer this definitively - the owner of the IP can choose to start and stop making movies at will, regardless of what plot points have been resolved.

Comment: we can only hope so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. As long as a franchise remains profitable, there will continue being some way of continuing the series. In FD, there is no physical antagonist chasing you (E.G. Freddy, Jason, Michael Meyers, Alien, Predator... you get the idea), and after the second film, there has been virtually no clear connection between the characters of the first two films and the rest (other than the ending to FD5).

Besides, even when a franchise has more than run its course (think of how many Friday The 13th films there were with the 'original' Jason), there is currently the fashionable idea of 'rebooting' a series. They did it with Halloween, they'll likely do it with FD in another 5-10 years time.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination_%28film_series%29#Future)-

> On February 1, 2011, Tony Todd said in an interview with DreadCentral
>   that if Final Destination 5 is a success at the box office, then two
>   sequels would be filmed back-to-back. On August 23, 2011, when
>   inquired whether he will be directing a sequel, Stephen Quale
>   elaborates, "Who knows. Never say never. I mean, it'll be up to the
>   fans. We'll see how this one performs internationally and if it makes
>   as much money as the fourth one, I'm sure Warner Brothers will want to
>   make another one." With the success of Final Destination 5, it is
>   likely that a sixth film will be made, though Warner Bros. has yet to
>   confirm this

That means most probably there may be two more entries in the movie series. As the 5<sup>th</sup> one is a prequel to the series. There are rumours for the next one to be a mid-equal.

Final Destination Wikia also says yes for FD6 and FD7.([SOURCE](http://finaldestination.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Destination_6))

Comment: "mid-equal"... my new word for the day